# How to use Firebase Authentication tokens from login in site in an Android application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an Angular site implementing Firebase Authentication and it works fine in conjunction with my Node.JS app server using Admin SDk.
I.e. I can login a user in the site, send the token to the app server and get the logged-in user object on my server.
I then share the token with an Android App but the token is not recognized when using firebase SDK in Android.
I use code similar to this example:

```
private void handleWebToken(String webToken) {
    // Create an AuthCredential using the web token
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(webToken, null);

    // Sign in with the AuthCredential
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // User authentication is successful
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // You can get the user details like email, display name, etc.
                    String email = user.getEmail();
                    String displayName = user.getDisplayName();
                }
            } else {
                // User authentication failed
            }
        });
}
```

But I always get a null user.
I tried enabling the Authentication methods in the Android firebase project but that did not help.
Note: Each implementation is in a different firebase project: site, server and Android app.

Update 02-August-2023:
Looks like it is not trivial to share tokens and users across firebase projects.
According to Bing AI chat:

> No, 2 different Firebase projects cannot share authentication users and user tokens. Each Firebase project has its own user database and authentication system, and they are not compatible with each other.

Update 03-August-2023:
I tried creating a second FirebaseApp in my Android app with my web project's config using the instructions here:

[Configure multiple projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#java)

but I still get 'FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException' when trying to sign-in with 'FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(...)' with the token received from my back-end and then calling 'FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()'.

Answer (score 0):

Did you confirm the task was actually successful? If sign in was successful you would not be getting `user == null` so it must be that you are entering the `else` statement without realising

Comment: I ran it in the debugger and saw it with my own eyes!